# Rust ownership when returning struct

Tags: rust

I'm fairly new to rust and I thought one way to learn it is to make a game in it. To make the game I'm using sdl2 (doesn't matter), but the code started to get messy. So I decided to split it up into different files. In of those files, I have created a struct, which has a public new function. Which will create a new instance of the struct.

```rust
pub struct Screen {
    sdl_context: Sdl,
    video_subsystem: VideoSubsystem,
    window: Window,
    event_pump: EventPump,
    canvas: Option<WindowCanvas>,
    pub width: u32,
    pub height: u32
}

impl Screen {
    pub fn new(width: u32, height: u32, title: &str) -> Self {
        let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
        let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();
        let window = WindowBuilder::new(&video_subsystem, title, width, height).position_centered().build().unwrap();
        let canvas = window.into_canvas().accelerated().build().unwrap();
        let event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();

        Screen {sdl_context, canvas, event_pump, height, video_subsystem, width, window}
    }
}
```

My error: `` error[E0382]: use of moved value: `window` --> src/screen.rs:23:82 let window = WindowBuilder::new(&video_subsystem, title, width, height).position_centered().build().unwrap(); ------ move occurs because `window` has type `sdl2::video::Window`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait let canvas = window.into_canvas().accelerated().build().unwrap(); ------------- `window` moved due to this method call Screen {sdl_context, canvas, event_pump, height, video_subsystem, width, window}                                                                                  ^^^^^^ value used here after move ``

The problem I'm facing here is that most of the variables don't implement the `Copy` trait which results in an error about ownership when I try to make the struct with those variables. I have tried using references but the variable will not live long enough.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman oh sorry, I completely forgot.

Comment: Do you need to keep the `window` around? Because `.into_canvas()` will *consume* the `window`. There are [methods](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.window) to get the window back from the canvas if you need it.

Comment: @kmdreko I didn't know that it took ownership of the window. After removing the window, it seems to work. Can you turn this into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [`.into_canvas()`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/video/struct.Window.html#method.into_canvas) on the `window` which takes ownership of it. It takes `self` (not `&self`) as the self parameter. Therefore you don't have it anymore to store in your struct; it has been moved elsewhere.

The [`WindowCanvas`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/type.WindowCanvas.html) you end up with will have ownership of the `Window`. There are methods like [`.window()`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.window)/[`window_mut()`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.window_mut)/[`into_window()`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/latest/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.into_window) that you can use to access the window from the canvas if you need to.